# How would I go about this?(Android Whack-A-Mole Project)

Tags: android

I'm making a simple whack-a-mole game as my first mini-project for android. I'm not sure how to go about this. I know the basics of setting everything up and such but I'm not sure how to animate the moles and make it so that when the mole is in the up position it can be tapped and a point will be counted. I know I can do an image button and have a counter go up(counter++) but I need to be able to switch frames from the mole in the hole to the mole in the up position. Anyone have an idea as to how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I do this?(Android Whack-A-Mole)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022105/how-would-i-do-thisandroid-whack-a-mole)

Answer (score 0):

Android allows you to animate objects in a variety of ways. If you only need 2 images to switch, like a button with 'pushed' / 'not pushed' states, you can use a special type of Drawable called a selector (which allows you to specify different drawables for the various states of the target).

If you need more than two images, you may want to use the simple View animation that Android allows you to create using xml. For instance, you can create an xml animation that specifies an image to move/rotate/scale from one initial position to another, creating the in-between frames for you. 
Android also has a newer, more complex and full-featured form of animation (which you probably don't need to go into).
Both of these animation systems are detailed at :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html

Otherwise you will need to create a series of images that you iterate through at a steady pace (which is the fundamental idea behind animation).

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create a custom View - subclassing Button, that simply animates it's image using the View Animation above. This button will just have an image of a mole that moves up and down when clicked, and which is clickable only when it isn't animating

Comment: I'm a little confused, sorry(I just started android programming yesterday) Do you have an example of how that would work?

Answer (score 0):

I've already made this before, I'll give you an overview, just check my post here: [Simple Whack a Mole overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022105/how-would-i-do-thisandroid-whack-a-mole/12212444#12212444)